# org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.throwMessageTimeoutException(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:571)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I used publishSubscribeChannel and designed a threadPoolExecutor to handler some time consuming logics(about 1 minutes) with async as follow:

```
@Bean
        public IntegrationFlow performNameScreeningCaseFlow(){
            return IntegrationFlows.from(RTSChannel.PerformNameScreening.REQUEST_CHANNEL)
                    ...
                    .publishSubscribeChannel(RTSThreadPoolExecutor.rtsThreadPoolExecutor,subscribe->
                            subscribe.subscribe(flow->
                                    flow.gateway(RTSChannel.PerformNameScreeningSubFlow.REQUEST_CHANNEL,
                                            g->g.errorChannel(RTSChannel.PerformNameScreeningSubFlow.ERROR_CHANNEL))))
                    .transform(performNameScreeningResponseTransformer())
                    .enrichHeaders(c->c.header(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,HttpStatus.OK))
                    .get();
        }

        /**
         * sub flow
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow performNameScreeningCaseSubFlow(){
            return IntegrationFlows.from(RTSChannel.PerformNameScreeningSubFlow.REQUEST_CHANNEL)

               ...//Some time consuming logics
               .handle(performNameScreeningSubFlowRouteHandler::handlerCoreDocsResultAndUpdateRecord)
                    .get();
        }
```

And I was encountered the throwMessageTimeoutException exception when performance test.But time is fast, just entering mainflow on timeout(about 1 seconds)

```
MessageTimeoutException: No reply received within timeout
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.throwMessageTimeoutException(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:571)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:470)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:362)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:256)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sb.apiboot.policy.PolicyFilter.doFilter(PolicyFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapper.doFilter(ClientCertificateMapper.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

just like the threadExecutorPool was full and can't handler more request . but I have print some log in rejectHandler of threadExecutorPool and can't found anything.

Can you give me some suggestions? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your HTTP endpoint configuration but you can increase the timeout with `.replyTimeout(10_000)` for 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I was used the default  HTTP endpoint configuration. Under your reminder, I found that the default replyTime is 1s. And I want to know the meaning of this replyTime is to say that will timeout if publishSubscribeChannel  is no reply for 1 second?

Comment: And Gary. I was increase the timeout for 20 seconds. And in performance test , I found an method MessageTemplate.sendAndReceive( java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport:parkNanos) has cose 12 seconds. Do you know why?Is it because my thread pool tasks are very slow and can't reply the reuslt to mainFlow in time?

Comment: Once the thread returns to the template, it will wait for the replyTimeout for a reply.

Comment: Thanks. And I want to know is there a way to implement asynchronous, I mean do not wait for it to reply, directly hand the task to the thread pool to execute. Whether executed or queued.Because my condition does not allow mainFlow to wait too long

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question; if you don't wait for a reply (set it to 0), the `TimeoutException` will be thrown immediately. If you hand off the work to another thread, you must wait for the reply.

Comment: OK. I know . Thanks